# Which countries should I include in my travel history for UK Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

Context: I am an Indian national living in the Netherlands. I will be applying for a UK Standard Visa from Amsterdam.

So, everything else in the main form is clear but the travel history part is confusing me. I have an extensive travel history because I often take weekend trips to other countries in the EEA. But since I already live in the Netherlands, these are not officially recorded on my passport in the form of stamps or visas. These are over 20 countries.
Before moving to Europe, I have travelled to the EEA with a proper Schengen visa and these visits are indeed recorded on my passport.

So when the application form asks me how many times I've visited the EEA, Switzerland, Australia, Canada, US, New Zealand, what should I say? I've definitely visited EEA countries more than 6 times (which is last option on the form). So should I just select that option? Later they ask about my two most recent trips. These were Belgium and Italy but obviously I didn't need a separate visa for this and they aren't on my passport.

So my question is, should I tell them about my actual most recent trips or the most recent trips that can be verified on my passport in terms of stamps and visas?

Comment: The usual advice given on this site to visa question is: Be truthful. What will you answer if they ask whether you have ever been to Belgium if you did not declare it?

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm just a little confused by the terminology. The EEA as a whole or individual countries within the EEA? Another member seems to have had the same query a few years ago: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101015/uk-visa-application-listing-within-schengen-visits-when-youre-a-resident-of-t?rq=1 but I don't know if forms have changed since

Comment: If it says "EEA" and you are *in* the EEA and visit other countries *in* the EEA without going outside the EEA in between, it seems to me that those visits wouldn't really count.

Answer (score 15):

> But since I already live in the Netherlands, these are not officially recorded on my passport in the form of stamps or visas

The question is not asking you what stamps you have, it is asking you what countries you have visited.

> So when the application form asks me how many times I've visited the EEA, Switzerland, Australia, Canada, US, New Zealand, what should I say? I've definitely visited EEA countries more than 6 times (which is last option on the form). So should I just select that option?

Yes, because that's clearly the answer to the question.

> So my question is, should I tell them about my actual most recent trips or the most recent trips that can be verified on my passport in terms of stamps and visas?

You should answer the question being asked, not try and infer some other question.

Comment: Thanks! That's also what I thought but apparently they want to know our travel history so they can check compliance with previous visas? This is of course conjecture (as are most things about visas!).

Comment: @user69279 Sure, but it's not your responsibility to work out how they'll do that. In your case you have a Schengen visa so they should know you're free to travel within the Schengen area. Ultimately, the fact you have a long term Schengen visa means you'll be considered a low risk applicant, regardless of other travel history

Comment: Thanks, you're right! Just came across this and now I'm confused all over again: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101015/uk-visa-application-listing-within-schengen-visits-when-youre-a-resident-of-t?rq=1 But I think I prefer your answer.